# Data format for Ajax/jQuery request to backend

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Can someone please advise in which data format the below Ajax/jQuery request is sent to the backend.

Here is my Ajax/jQuery code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
        var $ul = $( this ),
            $input = $( data.input ),
            value = $input.val(),
            html = "";
        $ul.html( "" );
        if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
            $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "/get_names/",
                dataType: "json",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: {
                    q: $input.val()
                }
            })
            .then( function ( response ) {
                $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                    html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
                });
                $ul.html( html );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's JSON format:

```
{name1 : value1, name2 : value2}
```

At the backend you should be able to get this values just as simple as that:

```
$_GET['value1']
```